# Scala: Dependency Injection via Reader and compatibility

Tags: scala, oop, dependency-injection, functional-programming, reader-monad

When we implement DI via Reader, we make a dependency a part of our method signature. Assume we have (without implementations):

```
trait Service1 { def f1:Int = ??? }
trait Service2 { def f2:Reader[Service1, Int] = ??? }

type Env= (Service1, Service2)
def c:Reader[Env, Int] = ???  //use Service2.f2 here
```

Now, `f2` needs additional service for implementation, say:

```
trait Service3
type Service2Env = (Service1, Service3)
//new dependecies on both:
trait Service2 { def f2:Reader[Service2Env, Int] = ??? }
```

It will break existing clients, they cannot any longer use `Service2.f2` without providing `Service3` additionally.

With DI via injection (via constructor or setters), which is common in OOP, I would use as a dependency of `c` only `Service2`. How it is constructed and  what is its list of dependencies, I do not care. From this point, any new dependencies in `Service2` will keep the signature of `c` function unchanged.

How is it solved in FP way? Are there options? Is there a way to inject new dependencies, but somehow protect customers from the change?

Comment: *"It will break existing clients"*. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but if you add an additional parameter to the method, this will break in OOP as well, as you'll no longer be able to call that method without supplying the parameters?

Comment: Just like @YuvalItzchakov said, if you want to get rid of all (object instance) state (even "benign" immutable constructor-injected dependencies), then all of a function's dependencies have to become parameters, and those are to be supplied by the caller. No way around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to inject new dependencies, but somehow protect customers from the change?

That would kind of defeat the purpose, as using Reader (or alternatively Final Tagless or ZIO Environment) is a way to explicitly declare (direct and indirect) dependencies in the type signature of each function. You are doing this to be able to track where in your code these dependencies are used -- just by looking at a function signature you can tell if this code might have a dramatic side-effect such as, say, sending an email (or maybe you are doing this for other reasons, but the result is the same).

You probably want to mix-and-match this with constructor-injection for the dependencies/effects that do not need that level of static checking.